# Error creating SparkContext in pyspark example on a standalone cluster

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a standalone cluster started with 3 nodes. I am trying to get the pyspark example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/quick-start.html#a-standalone-app-in-python). I am running it step by step in python. I feel this is must be more related to the pyspark version that I installed versus the spark version I am using.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("spark://192.168.122.54:7077")
conf.setAppName("My application")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

The output:

```
20/05/05 20:20:15 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ronald-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.122.54 instead (on interface ens3)
20/05/05 20:20:15 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/05/05 20:20:16 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ronald/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 136, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/home/ronald/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 213, in _do_init
    self._encryption_enabled = self._jvm.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled(self._jsc)
  File "/home/ronald/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1487, in __getattr__
    "{0}.{1} does not exist in the JVM".format(self._fqn, name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM
```

If I just run it on the local node

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local")
conf.setAppName("My application")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

There is still the same error

```
20/05/05 20:16:29 WARN Utils: Your hostname, ronald-Standard-PC-i440FX-PIIX-1996 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.122.54 instead (on interface ens3)
20/05/05 20:16:29 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/spark-3.0.0-preview2-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/05/05 20:16:30 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ronald/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 136, in __init__
    conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
  File "/home/ronald/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 213, in _do_init
    self._encryption_enabled = self._jvm.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled(self._jsc)
  File "/home/ronald/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1487, in __getattr__
    "{0}.{1} does not exist in the JVM".format(self._fqn, name))
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonUtils.getEncryptionEnabled does not exist in the JVM
```

Comment: replace `conf.setMaster("spark://192.168.122.54:7077")` with `conf.setMaster("local")` as described in the link you posted.

Comment: But then I wont be able to run it on the cluster just on the local node.